# Filter a list of objects based on a property existing in another list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I've got a class named `Container` that includes an `int` property named `Id`.

I've got a list of objects `List<Container>` named `containers`.

I've got a list of numbers `List<int>` named `containerIds`.

How can I get a subset of containers where the `Id` is in `containerIds`?

Something like the following:

```
var result = containers.Where(x => x.Id IN containerIds);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1) method for that

```cs
var result = containers.Where(x => containerIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

Another option is to use [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) Linq method

```cs
var result = containers.Where(x => containerIds.Any(i => i == x.Id));
```